# how to insert data from 3 different tables into one table using the select command

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, aggregate-functions, sql-insert

here are my tables

`eleve` table

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idEleve        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| NomEleve       | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PrenomEleve    | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DateNaissEleve | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LieuNaissEleve | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| codeClasse     | varchar(30) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select *from eleve ;
+---------+-----------+-------------+----------------+----------------+------------+
| idEleve | NomEleve  | PrenomEleve | DateNaissEleve | LieuNaissEleve | codeClasse |
+---------+-----------+-------------+----------------+----------------+------------+
|       1 | brahim    | elmoctar    | 1996-08-19     | teyaret        | CP1        |
|       2 | mohamed   | elmoctar    | 2000-02-01     | teyaret        | CP2        |
|       3 | fatimetou | elmoctar    | 1995-05-19     | teyaret        | CP3        |
+---------+-----------+-------------+----------------+----------------+------------+
```

`note` table

```
mysql> desc note ;
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idAffectationProf | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| idEleve           | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| NoteTrimester1    | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| NoteTrimester2    | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| NoteTrimester3    | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from note ;
+-------------------+---------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| idAffectationProf | idEleve | NoteTrimester1 | NoteTrimester2 | NoteTrimester3 |
+-------------------+---------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|                 1 |       1 |          13.24 |          12.45 |          10.54 |
|                 2 |       1 |          10.24 |          17.45 |          18.54 |
|                 3 |       1 |          15.24 |          12.45 |          13.54 |
+-------------------+---------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`affectationMatiere` table

```
mysql> desc affectationMatiere ;
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idAffectationProf | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| codeClasse        | varchar(30) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| idProf            | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| codeMat           | varchar(30) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Annee             | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select *from affectationMatiere ;
+-------------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+
| idAffectationProf | codeClasse | idProf | codeMat | Annee      |
+-------------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+
|                 1 | CP1        |      1 | Math    | 2020-01-01 |
|                 2 | CP2        |      2 | PC      | 2020-02-02 |
|                 3 | CP3        |      1 | SN      | 2020-03-03 |
+-------------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`moyenne` table

```
mysql> desc moyenne ;
+---------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idEleve             | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Annee               | date    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| moyenneGlobaleEleve | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to insert `idEleve`, `Annee`, and the general average of each student in the `moyenne` table.

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO moyenne 
    SELECT E.idEleve,a.Annee, (note.NoteTrimester1 + note.NoteTrimester2 + note.NoteTrimester3)/3 AS NoteGlobal FROM eleve E,affectMatiere a, note;
```

but unfortunately the request returns 27 result instead of 3.
suddenly I executed the request without the insert into and here is what I found

```
mysql> SELECT E.idEleve,a.Annee, (note.NoteTrimester1 + note.NoteTrimester2 + note.NoteTrimester3)/3 AS NoteGlobal FROM eleve E,affectationMatiere a, note;
+---------+------------+--------------------+
| idEleve | Annee      | NoteGlobal         |
+---------+------------+--------------------+
|       1 | 2020-01-01 | 12.076666666666666 |
|       2 | 2020-01-01 | 12.076666666666666 |
|       3 | 2020-01-01 | 12.076666666666666 |
|       1 | 2020-02-02 | 12.076666666666666 |
|       2 | 2020-02-02 | 12.076666666666666 |
|       3 | 2020-02-02 | 12.076666666666666 |
|       1 | 2020-03-03 | 12.076666666666666 |
|       2 | 2020-03-03 | 12.076666666666666 |
|       3 | 2020-03-03 | 12.076666666666666 |
|       1 | 2020-01-01 | 15.409999999999998 |
|       2 | 2020-01-01 | 15.409999999999998 |
|       3 | 2020-01-01 | 15.409999999999998 |
|       1 | 2020-02-02 | 15.409999999999998 |
|       2 | 2020-02-02 | 15.409999999999998 |
|       3 | 2020-02-02 | 15.409999999999998 |
|       1 | 2020-03-03 | 15.409999999999998 |
|       2 | 2020-03-03 | 15.409999999999998 |
|       3 | 2020-03-03 | 15.409999999999998 |
|       1 | 2020-01-01 | 13.743333333333332 |
|       2 | 2020-01-01 | 13.743333333333332 |
|       3 | 2020-01-01 | 13.743333333333332 |
|       1 | 2020-02-02 | 13.743333333333332 |
|       2 | 2020-02-02 | 13.743333333333332 |
|       3 | 2020-02-02 | 13.743333333333332 |
|       1 | 2020-03-03 | 13.743333333333332 |
|       2 | 2020-03-03 | 13.743333333333332 |
|       3 | 2020-03-03 | 13.743333333333332 |
+---------+------------+--------------------+
27 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your query is that you are missing join conditions between the tables: this results in a cartesian product between the 3 tables. Note that, as far as concerns, you don't need to bring in the `eleve` table to generate the expected resultset.

Also, I think that you need aggregation to gather together notes of each (`eleve`, `annee`) across all `codeMat`s.

I think that the following query does what you want:

```
insert into moyenne 
select 
    n.idEleve,
    a.Annee, 
    avg(n.NoteTrimester1 + n.NoteTrimester2 + n.NoteTrimester3)/3 
from 
    note n
    inner join affectMatiere a on a.idAffectationProf = n.idAffectationProf
group by 
    n.idEleve,
    a.Annee
```

Answer (score 1):

You now build a Cartesian product but actually you want joins with conditions. Maybe you need left joins, if it's possible that there are students who hadn't attended any courses yet but should also be present in the result. You should also always write down the targeted columns in an `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO moyenne
            (ideleve,
             annee,
             moyenneglobaleeleve)
SELECT e.ideleve,
       a.annee,
       (notetrimester1
        + notetrimester2
        + notetrimester3)
       / 3
       FROM eleve e
            LEFT JOIN note n
                      ON n.ideleve = e.ideleve
            LEFT JOIN affectationmatiere am
                      ON am.idaffectationorof = n.idaffectationprof;
```